# Netgear GS108E switch, requires external ``management'' software?

Tags: networking, switch

Does anyone know if the so-called ``management'' features of the NetGear GS108E switch require external software to enable these features?  Specifically, the port monitoring and VLAN features.  One reference I found says it is built into the switch, another says not.  The download section on NetGear's site offers a Windows software download.

I ask here since the ProSafe switches are aimed at business customers.

Comment: How else would you enable or control those features?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Actual managed switches usually have a web server or a console built in that allows one to manage the switch.

Comment: Say it had a web server, how would you access it without external software? Would you compose HTTP requests by hand?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That would be a viable alternative. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GS108E appears to be reliant on the Prosafe Plus Configuration Utility and lacks a telnet/http server.

Here is a youtube clip of it in action http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RRFzyByh1U

Skip to 1:48 and you see it mentions no http/telnet.

There is a comment on this page http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122397 also moaning about lack of web interface.

Comment: I was hoping for first person experience, but the video is clear without a doubt on the point.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the v3 model of these, they can be managed via a web interface. No need to use the ProSafe software.

See FAQ 4 here: https://kb.netgear.com/25093/GS108Ev3-FAQs

Answer (score 1):

There are two articles in the german Linux Magazin describing the insecure protocol used for accessing and configuring these switches:

First article:
http://www.linux-magazin.de/Ausgaben/2012/10/Switch

Second Article with the documentation of the minimally improved "encryption" after the firmware update:
http://www.linux-magazin.de/Blogs/Insecurity-Bulletin/Gastbeitrag-Security-by-Obscurity-bei-Netgear-Switches

Unfortunately, these articles have never been brought to the north american and british editions. Please use your favourite translation tool :)

Answer (score 0):

GS108E has a Web GUI but it's bugged (firmware 2.06.03 EN):

The Web GUI stops after a couple of hours ...
It's not accessible anymore, only after a reboot.